# Why can't my program find the text file I want to open?

Tags: ruby

I am writing this code for a CS assignment in Ruby. I am just beginning in Ruby so I don't know much about it but I keep getting a no method error from this code like this:

```
V:\CS 300 RubyAssignment\lib\rubyAssignment.rb:13:in `categorize': undefined method `line' for #&lt;File:ruby1.txt (closed)&gt; (NoMethodError)
    from V:\CS 300 RubyAssignment\lib\rubyAssignment.rb:11:in `open'
    from V:\CS 300 RubyAssignment\lib\rubyAssignment.rb:11:in `categorize'
    from V:\CS 300 RubyAssignment\lib\rubyAssignment.rb:30
```

The code is below but I get a feeling my text files are in the wrong place. I use a NetBeans Ruby plugin and I don't know if my text files should be in the projects source file folder, test file folder or libraries folder in netbeans? It might be as simple as that any ideas?

```
# This program reads a file line by line,
# separating lines by writing into certain text files.
# PPQ - Pangrams, Palindromes, and Quotes

class PPQ
  def categorize
    file_pangram = File.new('pangram.txt', 'w')
    file_palindrome = File.new('palindrome.txt', 'w')
    file_quotes = File.new('quotes.txt','w')

    File.open('ruby1.txt','r') do |file|
      while line = file.gets
        if(file.line.reverse == file.line)
          file_palindrome.write line
          if(file.line.contains('a'&&'b'&&'c'&&'d'&&'e'&&'f'&&'g'&&'h'&&'i'&&'j'&&'k'&&'l'&&'m'&&'n'&&'o'&&'p'&&'q'&&'r'&&'s'&&'t'&&'u'&&'v'&&'w'&&'x'&&'y'&&'z'))
            file_pangram.write "file.line"
          else
            file_quotes.write "file.line"
          end
        end
      end
      file.close
      file_pangram.close
      file_palindrome.close
      file_quotes.close
    end
  end
end
my_ruby_assignment = PPQ.new
my_ruby_assignment.categorize
```

Comment: Why do you think this is not finding your file?  Did you actually read the error message?

Comment: Basically to make my question more simple, where should my text files be on my machine so netbeans can run this code? Do I need to specify the directory of ruby1.txt or just call ruby1.txt?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the location of the files, see my answer…

Comment: Yeah I know it something to do with my libraries folder. I have moved it directly onto my V drive where my projects are stored rather than in the actual project now but it still doesn't work

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice that but it still cant find the file

Comment: **That's not what the error message says** -- it's not that it can't find the file (if it couldn't, it wouldn't **get** that far), it's that your program doesn't say what you think it says!

Comment: @NathanielRatliff If it *actually* can't find the file (and I mean that it actually says exactly that), that is an entirely different and new problem.

Comment: Im guessing my contains method is wrong to search for pangrams (lines with every letter at least once). My program runs now but it seems very slow and hasn't finished running yet.

Comment: Sorry guys you were all right my brain stopped for a minute there. It works thanks for your help

Comment: As an aside, what are you expecting `file.line.contains('a'&&'b'&&'c'...)` to do?

Comment: Well it should be line.contains('a' . . 'z') I think now.

Comment: Basically I expect it to search for lines that contain every letter at least once (pangrams) else its a quote(anything else) or a palindrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue's in the error message!

`undefined method line`

In your while loop you're reading a line from `file` via `gets`, then storing it in `line`. This code:

```
if(file.line.reverse == file.line)
```

is therefore incorrect -- you don't need the `file.` prefix! Ruby thinks you're trying to call the `line` method of the `file` object, which it doesn't have. That's why it's giving you the error it did…